# Difference between navigation window and navigation frame in WPF

Tags: wpf

Difference between navigation window and navigation frame in WPF ?
Both provide the same functionality of providing something like a content placeholder for containing pages .. so whats the big difference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that one is a [frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) and the other is a [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx).

If you already have a window of your own, you may only need the frame.

If that answer isn't exactly helpful, maybe you could rephrase your question.

Comment: I get it..I was actually trying to find the difference between a window and a navigation window ? I can create a window and have a frame inside it.So is that I go for a navigation window ?

Answer (score -1):

See Inheritance Hierarchy

NavigationWindow Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Frame Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx

They have almost same hierarchy, but ...
I got more UI responsiveness for may application when using NavigationWindow

Comment: Don't post link as answer. What if someone is looking for the solution and the link doesn't exist anymore? Please edit your answer and explain the content of the page. (Keeping the link to your source in your answer is still welcome)